# How to fix this assignment on java

Tags: java

How would I add an exception to print "Element not found in array"

The Assignment:

Create a Java program with a method that searches an integer array for a specified integer value (see help with starting the method header below). If the array contains the specified integer, the method should return its index in the array. If not, the method should throw an Exception stating "Element not found in array" and end gracefully. Test the method in main with an array that you make and with user input for the "needle".

My Code:

```
package chapter12;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] haystack = { 1,2,3,10,11,12,320,420,520,799,899,999 }; 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);                         
        System.out.println("Enter a number in the array: ");         
        int needle = sc.nextInt();                                  
        int index = returnIndex(haystack, needle);                   
        if(index!=-1)
        System.out.println("Element found at index : " + index);    
    }
    public static int returnIndex(int[] haystack, int needle) {
        for (int n = 0; n < haystack.length; n++) {                 
            if (haystack[n] == needle)
                return n;
    }
        System.out.println("Element not found in array");           
        return -1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: `throw new Exception("Element not found in array");`

Answer (score 5):

To throw an exception, you simply use the throw keyword:

`throw new Exception("Element not found in array");`

To end gracefully, you need to catch the exception in your main method using a `try { ... } catch(Exception e){ ..}` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Throw an exception from returnIndex method and catch the same exception in main method.

Below is the sample. I have used already existing NoSuchElementException.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] haystack = {1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 320, 420, 520, 799, 899, 999};
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number in the array: ");
    int needle = sc.nextInt();
    try {
        int index = returnIndex(haystack, needle);
        System.out.println("Element found at index : " + index);
    }catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }
}

public static int returnIndex(int[] haystack, int needle) throws NoSuchElementException {
    for (int n = 0; n < haystack.length; n++) {
        if (haystack[n] == needle)
            return n;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Element not found in array");
}
```

NOTE: It is used only for demo purpose. Ideally you should not catch Runtime Exception.